# Can a limit of multivariable function can be taken componentwise?

Tags: limits, functions

Is there a theorem saying that $\lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow(p,q)} f(x,y)= \lim_{x\rightarrow p}(\lim_{y\rightarrow q} f(x,y))$? If so, could someone link me to a proof of it or give me a proof?

Edit: So this is not true in general. What about when the all component limits exist everywhere? i.e. when $\lim_{x\to x_0}f(x,y)$ exists for all $y$ and $\lim_{y\to y_0}f(x,y)$ exists for all $x$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.  For a counterexample see

$$\lim \frac{xy}{x^2+y^2}$$ as (x,y) goes to (0,0).  The componentwise limit is 0, but the limit does not exist.  However, if the limit does exist, then the cimpotentwise limit will equal to actual limit.

Comment: "if the limit does exist, then the compotentwise limit will equal to actual limit."



How do we know that this is true?

Comment: For the limit to exist, it has to exist and equal that limit for every possible path to the point.  The componentwise limits are just 2 such possible paths.

Comment: No, one of the componentwise limits is _not_ the limit of $f$ along a path (unless we assume that $f$ is continuous or something).

Comment: If the final limit does exist than the componentwise limit is certainly the limit of f along a path.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. Could you point me to a proof that the limit of $f$ along any path is equal to the vector limit?

Comment: Yes, if the limit exists then the componentwise limit is the limit along a path. For a trivial and irrelevant reason - in that case the limit along _any_ path is the same as the componentwise limit. There is no path such that in general the limit along that path is the same as the componentwise limit